# How to make 2 lines of text on one in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im terrible at explaining. I have the words "Tasty Burger" over eachother but want them on one line.

```css
.footer-container {
    margin: 25px 0;
    display: flex;
    gap: 3rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.footer-item {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer-item">
      <img src="assets/img/logo-footer.png" alt="Tasty Burger Logo" />
      <h2>Tasty Burger</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-item">
      <h4>
        A burger is more than just a sandwich, it is a wish fulfilled.
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the image.
[image: Tasty Burger Image]

I need it to look like this:
[image: Tasty Burger Image Mockup]

I keep messing around with flexbox and the justify-content stuff but I think I'm in the totally wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
.footer-item h2{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And make sure the parent element has enough width to contain the text.